# How to create more than one block with different .tpl file(theme) in single module in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, module

How to create more than one block with different .tpl file(theme) in single module in drupal 7

Suppose I have a module name "mymodule", I want to create two blocks of this module name as "myblock1" and "myblock2" and these two block should be associated with two different tpl file like "block1.tpl.php" and "block2.tpl.php"

Please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has a flexible template suggestion system that should work here. Just name your template files appropriately and the templates will be applied. In your case you will want to name the tpl files

```
block--module--delta.tpl.php
```

Where *module* is your module name and *delta* is the id you assign to the block in your module.

More information at https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656